# Find corresponding value for a key in a map

Tags: apex, map

```
map<string, string> myMap = new map<string, string>();
myMap.put('1', 'One');
myMap.put('2', 'Two');
myMap.put('3', 'Three');
myMap.put('4', 'Four');
myMap.put('5', 'Five');
```

how do i find corresponding value using key?

myMap.containsKey('3') gives boolean but how do I get corresponding value of 'Three' in the above case?

Comment: myMap.get('3');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [map `get()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_get) method.... [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_get)

like

```
myMap.get(key);
```

in your case key will be `3,4,5...etc`

so try  `myMap.get('3');` this will give you 3rd respective value